# How do a gremlin's unluck aura and Perfect Strike interact?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monsters

The benefit of the feat [Perfect Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/perfect-strike-combat) says

> You can roll your attack roll twice and take the higher result. If one of these rolls is a critical threat, the other roll is used as your confirmation roll (your choice if they are both critical threats).

The [pugwampi](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/gremlins/gremlin-pugwampi) gremlin's unluck aura says

> A pugwampi radiates an aura of unluck to a radius of 20 feet. Any creature in this area must roll two d20s whenever a situation calls for a d20 roll (such as an attack roll, a skill check, or a saving throw) and must use the lower of the two results generated.

A warrior possessing the feat [Perfect Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/perfect-strike-combat)—and lacking a luck bonus to offset the aura's effect—uses the feat's benefit while within a [pugwampi](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/gremlins/gremlin-pugwampi) gremlin's unluck aura. How is the result of the warrior's attack determined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## This GM would take a shortcut…

The benefit of the feat [Perfect Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/perfect-strike-combat) pretty neatly (for the most part) cancels the attack roll part of the drawback of the [pugwami gremlin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/gremlins/gremlin-pugwampi)'s unluck aura. This GM would simplify things and say the warrior makes his attacks normally when using the feat Perfect Strike's benefit while affected by the unluck aura, the remaining drawbacks of the gremlin's unluck aura affecting the warrior normally. Such a shortcut isn't (*ahem*) perfect, but it'll speed play.

### …But another GM may complicate the situation

The dice-heavy alternative appears to be that an unlucky-yet-Perfect-Striking warrior rolls 2d20 twice, each time setting aside the die that rolled lower. Then the warrior uses the *higher* of the two set-aside dice as his attack roll. That's the consensus reached in this Paizo messageboard thread from [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mnze?Unluck-vs-Perfect-Strike#1) and a similar thread from [2012](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2nevd?Misfortune-and-perfect-strike#11), although this latter ostensibly about the [witch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch)'s [hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch#TOC-Hex) [misfortune](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes---3rd-party-publishers/hexes/common-hexes/hex-misfortune-su)'s interaction with the feat Perfect Strike.

Comment: Alternately in the second situation, a nice GM would allow you to keep the 2 high rolls, then use the lower of those two.