# What happens if I'm the target of both a Misfortune and a Fortune hex?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

So let's say I am a fighter, and there is a witch in my party. We are fighting a bad witch. My witch uses the *fortune* hex on me, and the bad witch uses the *misfortune* hex on me.

What happens on my next attack?

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83877/8610)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By RAW, nothing indicates that the hexes cancel, so both have their effect.

Fortune, for reference:

> The target can call upon this good luck once per round, allowing him to reroll any ability check, attack roll, saving throw, or skill check, taking the better result.

Misfortune, for reference:

> Anytime the creature makes an ability check, attack roll, saving throw, or skill check, it must roll twice and take the worse result.

First observe that misfortune affects all checks, while fortune only affects a single check. The rolls only affected by misfortune are not problematic, so let us consider the roll affected by both.

There are two possible orders of operation; one can start by applying either the fortune or the misfortune and continue with the other. Alternatively, one can try to dodge the issue of order of operations entirely.

1. Fortune is applied first and gives a reroll. Now we are rolling twice and taking the better roll. Since it is a reroll, both of the rolls are still ability checks (or whatever the original roll was). [This is a weak point in the argument. I'm not sure if this is true.] Misfortune is applied next separately to both of the rolls. That is, we first roll two dice, taking the worse; then we roll other two dice, keeping the worse; finally, we compare the results we did not discard and take the better of them. As a formula, the result is max(min(d20, d20); min(d20, d20)).
2. Fortune is applied first and gives a reroll. We treat this as a single check, which happens to involve rolling dice twice (and taking the better result). Misfortune is then applied; since it is applied to the check as a whole, we get two such rolls and have to take the worse result. As a formula, we get min(max(d20, d20); max(d20, d20))
3. Misfortune is worded in a slightly different manner. If we consider both of the rolls to be distinct checks, then we get the following result: Misfortune forces the character to roll two dice (and take the worse). Activating fortune allows the character to replace one of those with two rolls of which one takes the better. All in all, you get min(max(d20, d20); 20).
4. If we first consider misfortune and interpret the situation as one check, even though the die is rolled twice, we roll it again, and get exactly the same result as in option one, above.
5. If we apply both fortune and misfortune independently on the original check, we should be rolling three dice and taking both the best and the worst. Taking the best is equivalent to not taking the worst when we only have two dice, and likewise taking the worst is equivalent to not taking the best when we only have two dice. When we have three dice, taking both the best and the worst does not work, while taking neither the best nor the worst means that we take the middle one (median), which is at least possible, and not an entirely outlandish interpretation of the rules. This would mean that the probability distribution is more flat when both fortune and misfortune have been applied then if neither had.
6. Or we could simply say that both of the hexes cancel on the roll where both are in effect. This is the simplest solution, but also completely unsupported by RAW.

Personally, I would go with option 5, since it is nicely symmetric and has both of the hexes have an effect. Option 6 would be equally good. Options 1-4 are significantly more complicated, even though they might be slightly more supported by the written rules.